# show custom post type category dropdown sorting result on same page

Tags: posts, customization

I made a custom post type "kaubad" and i also want to add sorting option on website front end - users can select between this custom post type categories.

[here](http://imageshack.us/f/515/omarimartatooted2012081.png/) is screenshot about what i want to do.

but i want to do it with costum post type and display results also on costum post type page(on same page where i can filter posts by categories).

When i choose custom post type category,then only thing that will change is category ID on my web browser nav bar.
Results i got so far are like,example:tooted/?cat=15

[here is this post type page full code so far](http://pastie.org/4493048)

Sorry for my bad english,its not my native language,but i tried to explain it as good as i can.

Comment: Place the code only for Dropdown query. You have linked your full page script, which is not necessary. It's confusing to understand. Please correct it and minimize it to understand easily by others. Thanks.